# Android Studio Building Gradle project info stuck with no status after update to 2.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

After the update of Android Studio to 2.1.3 when creating a new project the building Gradle project info gets stuck with no info. At one point, I waited for 20 minutes with no change. Here:

[image]

Comment: Next time don't wait so many, check the cpu usage of the eclipse/gradle process and if is doesn't use the cpu, then it is dead.

Comment: Well same happened with me. In the end I had to end process by task manager. After that, i again fired up android-studio and all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me. My solution was to delete the gradle folder which I had left from a previous installation.

The folder path on Linux systems is `~/.gradle`.
After deleting this folder, a restart of Android Studio should do it.